# toggleclass on multiple items within same jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and have created 2 pages, both with multiple divs that are clickable.  I only want one div selected at a time, so if another one had been selected, it's selected class should be removed only on the active page.
Right now it also removes the selected class from the second page.
I have tried multiple things, i.e. having separate class names etc. but I can't get it to work.
What would be the best way to do this?

```
     <section id="LevelStartPage" data-role="page" class="ui-page-theme-b">
    <article id="LevelStartContent" data-role="content" class="ui-content">

        <h3>Select Starting Level</h3>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">

            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class='sprite style Black1'>1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Black</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class='sprite style VeryDarkBrown2'>2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Very Dark Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style DarkBrown3">3</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Dark Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style MediumBrown4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Medium Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightBrown5">5</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Light Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style DarkBlonde6">6</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Dark Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style MediumBlonde7">7</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Medium Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightBlonde8">8</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Light Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style VeryLightBlonde9">9</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext last">Very Light Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightestBlonde10">10</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext last">Lightest Blonde</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#LevelEndPage" class="ui-btn btn-rt ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext">Next</a>
    </article>
</section>

<section id="LevelEndPage" data-role="page" class="ui-page-theme-b">

    <article id="LevelEndContent" data-role="content" class="ui-content">
        <h3>Select Ending Level</h3>
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class='sprite style Black1'>1</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Black</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class='sprite style VeryDarkBrown2'>2</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Very Dark Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style DarkBrown3">3</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Dark Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style MediumBrown4">4</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Medium Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightBrown5">5</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Light Brown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style DarkBlonde6">6</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Dark Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style MediumBlonde7">7</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Medium Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightBlonde8">8</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext">Light Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style VeryLightBlonde9">9</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext last">Very Light Blonde</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="sprite style LightestBlonde10">10</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="spritetext last">Lightest Blonde</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sprite.style, .spriteGray.style').on('click', function () {
        $('.sprite.style, .spriteGray.style').removeClass('selected')
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need separate click handlers for each block. Include your article id in the selectors so their specific to section.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#LevelStartContent .sprite.style').on('click', function () {
        $('#LevelStartContent .sprite.style').removeClass('selected')
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $('#LevelEndContent .sprite.style').on('click', function () {
        $('#LevelEndContent .sprite.style').removeClass('selected')
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/2VLMQ/

Comment: @SheriTrager `ready` shouldn't be used in JQM, instead use page events.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sprite.style, .spriteGray.style').on('click', function () {
        $('.ui-page-active .sprite.style, .spriteGray.style').removeClass('selected')
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Added .ui-page-active to the selector